# angular "query" property : where is it defined?

Tags: angularjs

AngularJS noob here.

I'm going thru the tutorial (https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_03) and see this in the example index.html template:

```
Search: <input ng-model="query">
```

I don't see any mention of a 'query' property in the accompanying JS files (controllers.js, etc).

Is `query` a property of the `$scope` object?  If so is there a documentation for it?  Can't seem to find one.

Thanks!

Comment: Reads through the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: You don't need to declare it before using it. The framework would create it if it does not find one on the scope where the input is defined.

Comment: thank you, this implicit creation mechanism is cool to have!

Answer (score 0):

In this example `query` is not used in the JavaScript at all, so it isn't mentioned there.

It is created by `<input ng-model="query">` and later used by the filter in `phone in phones | filter:query`.

With this html Angular watches for changes to `query` from typing into `<input>` and then reapplies the `ng-repeat` passing the new `query` value to `filter`.